# R: How to join multiple plots into one plot?

Tags: r, plot

I have two density distribution data A and B, I want to plot the two density curves into one plot. I used the following codes:

```
plot(user.dens.tas, col="red", xlim=c(0,0.003))
plot(item.dens.tas, col="blue", xlim=c(0,0.003))
```

**How can I plot the two curves into one plot (combine them)?**

[image]

Comment: On second line use `lines()` instead of `plot()`.

Comment: how to do this in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
plot(user.dens.tas, col="red", xlim=c(0,0.003))
lines(item.dens.tas, col="blue", xlim=c(0,0.003))
```

Puts one line in read, the other in blue on the same plot. You might also consider [adding a title](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html) and other presentation niceties.

Comment: do you know how to do this in python?